# Is it possible to manage a device instead of a connection with Ansible 'nmcli' module?

Tags: ansible, nmcli

I have to apply the following configuration on several hosts via Ansible:

```
nmcli device modify "device_name" ens192 ipv6.method "disabled"
```

I wanted to use the `nmcli` module instead of a command as it is cleaner. But from what I found on the documentation and forums the `nmcli` module manage only connections.

Apart from recovering all connections associated to an interface and modifying each one using Ansible `nmcli` module I could not find a way to do it. This solution beeing, in my opinion, uglier than using command module I will stick with command.

Any informed comment or suggestion would be appreciated.

For the sake of precision the current code used to disable ipv6 if networkmanager is used:

```yaml
- name: get service facts
  service_facts:

- name: Disable ipv6 with network manager
  become: yes
  command: "/bin/nmcli device modify {{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }} ipv6.method 'disabled'"
  when: ansible_facts.services["NetworkManager.service"] is defined
  changed_when: false
```

Comment: I have never used the module but [its documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html) gives a quite different overview in terms of support than what your report in your question. First line of synopsys `Manage the network devices. Create, modify and manage various connection and device type e.g., ethernet, teams, bonds, vlans etc.`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question fully since there is no example what you have tried, problem description, description of your system, used versions, confguration or error messages.

---

Regarding

> *I wanted to use the `nmcli` module instead of a command as it is cleaner*

and according the documentation of the module [`nmcli`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html) there is a parameter [`ifname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html#parameter-ifname)

> *The interface to bind the connection to.
> The connection will only be applicable to this interface name.
> A special value of `'*'` can be used for interface-independent connections.
> The ifname argument is mandatory for all connection types except bond, team, bridge, vlan and vpn.
> This parameter defaults to `conn_name` when left unset for all connection types except vpn that removes it.*

So looking at the CLI output of `nmcli device show`

```bash
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         AB:CD:EF:01:02:03
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     eth0
...
```

and since `conn_name` obviously points to `GENERAL.CONNECTION`, wouldn't that parameter
`ifname` for `GENERAL.DEVICE` not be that one which you are looking for?

The [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html#examples) are showing also the usage of `ifname` together with `conn_name`.

Furthermore `ipv6.method disabled` isn't available in example in RHEL 7, but as of 8.

```yaml
- name: Make sure IPv6 is disabled
  shell:
    cmd: nmcli conn mod eth0 ipv6.method disabled
  when: ansible_distribution == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '8'
```